# Hierarchy Viewer not working with emulator

Tags: android

I'm having difficulties getting Hierarchy Viewer working with the emulator. I get these error messages, but I don't understand how I can resolve them:

```
    [2014-01-22 09:47:47 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device emulator-5554
    [2014-01-22 09:47:47 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: emulator-5554
    [2014-01-22 09:47:48 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for emulator-5554
    [2014-01-22 09:47:48 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device emulator-5554
```

I've tried within Eclipse and also from Android Device Monitor, I've restarted adb in and out of Eclipse and also sudo or not sudo. None of these things made any difference. I couldn't find anyone else having these issues, so assumed some platform/setup issue (I'm running latest updates of Android SDK and Linux Mint 16), however tried on a Windows 7 machine with an older (non-updated SDK) and got the exact same result.

Please does anyone know the inner mechanics of these messages, can anyone suggest steps to diagnose/fix the problem?

thanks for all help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except it happens to work every so often (but less often than not working). I've tried Romain's ViewServer along with all the other things stillsw tried as well.